# HTML date field not able to set back to date field coming from backend

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, momentjs

I have an HTML Date field.
I have a create page where I am inserting date to MySQL db
I have a edit page where i am fetching the date and set back to input field.

```
<input id="dob" name="dob" type="date" placeholder="Enter date of birth" class="form-control" ng-model="user.dob"/>
```

**JS**

```
function loadUserById() {
        ApiService.getById($scope.id).then(function(response) {
            $scope.user = response.data[0];
            $scope.user.password1 = response.data[0].password;

            if($scope.user.dob) {
                var date = new Date($scope.user.dob);
                $scope.user.dob = moment(date).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
            }
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

**Problem**

I am inserting date from this field in to MySQL database and I am formatting it as `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Then I am formatting to `mm/dd/yyyy` format and trying to set it in the HTML Date field.

but it is throwing an error:

```
angular.js:14642 Error: [ngModel:datefmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/ngModel/datefmt?p0=06%2F03%2F2018
at angular.js:88
at Array.<anonymous> (angular.js:25252)
at angular.js:29245
at m.$digest (angular.js:18202)
at m.$apply (angular.js:18480)
at l (angular.js:12501)
at XMLHttpRequest.s.onload (angular.js:12655)
```

Comment: See [this link](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.5/docs/error/ngModel/datefmt?p0=03-06-2018). The date is clearly not in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. You may try to format it in the MySQL query, so that the date is returned in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: no i am formatting it in client site then i am setting to date field

Comment: Please read the link in my first comment, the description, precisely. It will guide you on why this error comes.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer.
Need to use ng-value then it'll automatically set the date in to the field.

```
function loadUserById() {
        ApiService.getById($scope.id).then(function(response) {
            $scope.user = response.data[0];
            $scope.user.password1 = response.data[0].password;

            if($scope.user.dob) {
                var date = new Date($scope.user.dob);
                $scope.user.dob = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
            }
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }


<input id="dob" name="dob" type="date" ng-readonly="readOnly" placeholder="Enter date of birth" class="form-control" ng-model="user.dob" ng-value="user.dob"/>
```